# call class from jar

Tags: java

How to call method from callapi.jar file?Callapi.jar file contains callapi package with callapi.class inside.

And another problem how to call it from another jar. I mean staticapi.jar contains staticapi package with file staticapi.class and callapi.jar. Callapi.jar is called by staticapi.

Comment: Is this class the main class of the jar? What do you mean by calling it?

Comment: Yes. Jar contains only one package with one class.

Comment: Please ask a meaningful question, rather than stating a cryptic scenario with no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually call class from a jar using following command:

```
java -cp myJar.jar mypackage.myclass
```

In this case, assuming you have `callapi` class inside `callapi` package in `callapi.jar`, try executing following command:

```
java -cp callapi.jar callapi.callapi
```

Now, in the code, you you can import this class using

```
import mypackage.myclass
```

But you must put the jar containing this class in the classpath.

Comment: Uh-oh, one can instantiate a class, it's not a call (in your example you run it).

Comment: This was reply to `How to call class from callapi.jar file?`. Am I wrong? o_O