# call method from class in jar file

Tags: java, jar

Ask previous question but in another form.

Class callapi contains method MainMethod(String name). I put this class in jar file callapi.jar.

Class staticapi calls method MainMethod from jar.
So question:
How to call method MainMethod(String name) from callapi.jar?

P.s staticapi class and callapi.jar are in staticapi.jar

Comment: possible duplicate of [call class from jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966060/call-class-from-jar)

Comment: Yes. But I ask it in another form.

Comment: If you aren't getting relevant answers to your previous question, then you should improve that question.  You shouldn't start a new, equivalent, question.

Comment: But I asked it in this forum.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: The OP said "form", not "forum".  But either way, he shouldn't be posting duplicates.

Comment: sorry. comments deleted.

Answer (score 0):

import PACKAGE.callapi;

add the call as

new callApi().MainMethod(name_toBePassed);

PS:- the jar file should be in the class path of JVM